# Ansible: How do I get a host by index number in the host group

Tags: variables, ansible, ansible-inventory, inventory

I have this host group in the inventory

```
[test-node]
usprz3-sec-asept-dz03.prz.foo.com
usprz3-sec-asept-dz04.prz.foo.com
```

I want to print these host names in a file via the .j2 template
I don't want to iterate over the list, I simply want to print the first item in the group in one place and the 2nd item in another place. Is there a way something like below that would give me the desired effect?

```
[test-node].0    should print usprz3-sec-asept-dz03.prz.foo.com
[test-node].1    usprz3-sec-asept-dz04.prz.foo.com
```

My ansible version is ansible 2.5.4

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

List of groups and hosts is available in [Special Variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html). The task below

```
- template:
    src: test-template.j2
    dest: test.txt
```

and the template (test-template.j2)

```
{% for item in groups['test-node'] %}
[test-node].{{loop.index}}    {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

gives:

```
> cat test.txt
[test-node].1    usprz3-sec-asept-dz03.prz.foo.com
[test-node].2    usprz3-sec-asept-dz04.prz.foo.com
```

Comment: Vladimir, thanks for your reply. Suppose I don't want to loop through the group, (because I want the host names in different places, not consequely one after other.) Can I refer to them as  groups['test-node'].1   and groups['test-node'].2     ?

Answer (score 1):

Taking on Vladimir's example, you can print the first host in the list as

```
{{ groups['test-node'].0 }}
```

This will print usprz3-sec-asept-dz03.prz.foo.com

and second host as

```
{{ groups['test-node'].1 }}
```

This will print usprz3-sec-asept-dz04.prz.foo.com